# How can I change icon of primefaces roweditor

Tags: primefaces, roweditor

Is there any way to change the icon of  for primefaces 5.3? I checked the answer in here and searched on the web, but could not figure it out.

Comment: CSS is your friend. Overwrite `.ui-row-editor > .ui-icon-pencil`

Comment: Just like using more generic questions (e.g How can I override/change a PrimeFaces icon)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

overwrite your the styles in your CSS and point to your icon image:

```
  .ui-row-editor > .ui-icon-pencil {
  background-image: url(../images/myPencil.png) !important;
  height: 20px;
  width:20px;
 }
```

Comment: When I try this it gives info about ui-icon-pencil is never used and also doesnt work what can I do more